# error in java sphinx program

Tags: java, exception, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

Hi i am making a software in java in which i want to develop a speech software... I am running a "Hello" sphinx code in java.

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.result.Result;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurationManager cm;

        if (args.length > 0) {
            cm = new ConfigurationManager(args[0]);
        } else {
            cm = new ConfigurationManager(HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml"));
        }

        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        recognizer.allocate();

        // start the microphone or exit if the programm if this is not possible
        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
        if (!microphone.startRecording()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
            recognizer.deallocate();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Say: (Good morning | Hello) ( Bhiksha | Evandro | Paul | Philip | Rita | Will )");

        // loop the recognition until the programm exits.
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");

            Result result = recognizer.recognize();

            if (result != null) {
                String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
                System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + '\n');
            } else {
                System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

while i try to run this program i got this error...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.SaxLoader.load(SaxLoader.java:74)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.<init>(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:22)
```

Please suggest...

Thanks

Comment: maybe your helloworld.config.xml could not be found

Answer (score 3):

i had the same error and fixed it. you simply will find a HelloWord.jar file in sphinx bin folder just include the jar file to your project and it will run normally

---

the path for the jar file :
sphinx4-1.0beta6-bin\sphinx4-1.0beta6\bin\HelloWorld.jar

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear which line is *actually* line 22 in your code, but I suspect it's this:

```
cm = new ConfigurationManager(HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml"));
```

My guess is that `helloworld.config.xml` can't be found, so `getResource` is returning null, which you're passing to the `ConfigurationManager`.

There are various reasons why the config may not be found, such as:

- It's not on the classpath (e.g. not bundled into a jar file, not copied to the `bin` directory by Eclipse)
- It's not in the right place - that code will try to find it relative to `HelloWorld.class`, whereas you might have it in the "package root"

It's hard to say any more without more information from you.

Assuming that *is* the case, it has nothing to do with Sphinx.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the src version, make sure you have lib/sphinx4.jar if not go to the top directory (sphinx4.0beta-src, for example) and type ant.

Then you can run it typing :

```
sphinx4> java -mx256m -jar bin/HelloWorld.jar
```

If you want more information go :[CMU-Sphinx-Helloword](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/src/apps/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/helloworld/README.html)